# Google Checkout error, "Build failed with an exception"

Tags: php, html, basic-authentication, google-checkout

I want to implement Google Checkout in my PHP project (running on Apache).  I put the callback URL in my merchant center account. My Checkout is in sandbox mode. When placing an order I get the following error message in my merchant center:

```
We encountered an error trying to access your server at myurl.org -- the error we got is 

 Send failed with code: 401. 
 Response body was: Failed to Get Basic Authentication Headers
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873568

Comment: Just to emphasize Gumbo's comment, this isn't simply a redundant question, it is the same question almost exactly, probably from the same person with a different user name or someone on the same project. Even the plea for urgency.

Comment: Closed the other (unedited, unanswered) version of the question and cleared the votes to close on this one.  @saif: If these two accounts are used by the same person, leave me a message and I can merge them.

Answer (score 0):

Since neither version of this question has been addressed, I figure I'll add some advice to the one I edited:

I'm not at all familiar with Google Checkout and its API, but a quick Wikipedia search for HTTP error informs me that a [401 error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error) is because authentication has failed. Note, this is not the same as the authentication being rejected (error 403: Forbidden) but rather that the actual attempt to authenticate failed. A good analogy might be to imagine going to a door, being asked for the secret password (which we'll say is *Fedelio*) and instead of saying "Applesauce" and getting beat up for trespassing (error 403) instead you respond with "Huh?" and the gate keeper simply stands there wondering if you even know what he meant by password.

The same wiki article refers to [Basic Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) in relationship to this error. I highly reccommend taking a look into that as well.

Long story short, your users need to authenticate when the URL is requested, but it sounds like you are trying to request the site server-side or through some kind of redirect, so the server is returning the 401 error instead of returning a login prompt.